# Utilizar DBLookupComboBox apenas com uma tabela e um ClientDataset

Tags: delphi

Pessoas, tenho uma dúvida na utilização do DBLookupCombobox no Delphi. 
É possível, ao invés de utilizar duas tabelas (pegar valores de uma e gravar em outra), eu ter apenas a tabela onde gravarei o valor selecionado a puxar os dados de um ClientDataset com os valores? 
Eu não quero criar uma tabela apenas para puxar os dados para o DBLC, gostaria de puxar os dados de um CDS com os valores.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim Rodrigo, basta você criar um `TDataSource` apontando para o seu ClientDataSet, e na propriedade do `DBLookupComboBox` você seta o `ListSource` para o seu `TDataSource` criado, e o `ListField` e `KeyField` para os campos de visualização  e chaves, respectivamente.

Lembrando que você não precisa necessariamente ter uma segunda tabela diretamente ligada ao seu `DBLookupComboBox` na propriedade `DataSource`, você consegue acessar o registro selecionado através da propriedade `KeyValue`, ela retorna o valor selecionado respectivo ao seu `KeyField`.